# Jquery Scroll to Element does not animate my scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Jquery code never animated it's scroll in the beginning, it just teleports to the element I assigned it to. 
HTML Code:

```
        <div class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Steampunk :: New vision</h1>
        <p class="lead">Steampunk :: New Vision is a Steampunk style RTS game developed by ATMOX.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a href="#Information" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
```

Clicking on the Anchor Learn more. It should animate itself to this Element:

```
<h3 class="margin20" id="Information">About the Game <br><h6> -and it's Developers</h6></h3>
```

yet it just teleports itself to it. I tried setting the time it should take doing the animation longer but this also did not work.

Javacode:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 4000);
}
});
```

Comment: could you provide a replicating example ? It works fine for me

Comment: Sure, how'd I do that? Which browser did you use for it? I used Chrome and Firefox, just asking, in case that might be the problem :)

Comment: Is that JS code running *after* the elements have been parsed? (I.e., in a document ready handler, and/or a script element that appears after the anchor?) If not it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can create fiddle/ SO snippet. i tested on chrome.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n6tzgfuy/ here's the fiddle

Comment: @nnnnnn Nope, I created the JScript in another file and linked it to the HTML  in the head, before elements are parsed.

Comment: you have not added Jquery. check the updated one https://jsfiddle.net/kejpufq1/ . Always check the developer console

Comment: @Deep That's weird. do you mean the Jquery lib? I do have that one in my HTML file.

Comment: in the fiddle it was not present. could you check if its added properly in your code ??

Comment: I am giving a solution using the SO snippet , check that code works fine if you add Jquery.

Comment: If you've linked in your JS file in the head but *not* used a document ready handler then that's the problem. Move the script element to just before the closing `</body>` tag and it should work.

Comment: @nnnnnn Got any example? Because when I move the `<script type="text/javascript" src="java/scroll.js "></script>` just before the `</body>` element the button won't do anything.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's dev console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are facing an issue because you have not added Jquery due to this anchot is performing its default action. i.e jump to the target element.

Here is the updated answer.

in your scroll.js **$(document).ready();** is not correct , it should be.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="#Information"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 4000);
    }
    });
});
```

The second issue is that you are override the jquery.min.js library with the the jquery.slim.min.js which does not have many functionalties including animation.

Remove these 2 lines from your index.html.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

everything should work fine after that.

```js
$('a[href="#Information"]').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
  if (target.length) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

#testcontainer {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.paragraph {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.margin20 {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.padding15 {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.headerclass {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}
/* */

.titleclass {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
/* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
/* Custom default button */

.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}
/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("Images/xvLjyle.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */

.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
/* Padding for spacing */

.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: .40rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}
.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}
/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%;
    /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 42rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="ATMOX">
  <meta name="author" content="ATMOX">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="java / scroll.js "></script>
  <title>Steampunk :: New Vision</title>
  <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="inner cover">
  <h1 class="cover-heading">Steampunk :: New vision</h1>
  <p class="lead">Steampunk :: New Vision is a Steampunk style RTS game developed by ATMOX.</p>
  <p class="lead">


    <a href="#Information" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="testcontainer">

</div>


<h3 class="margin20" id="Information">About the Game <br><h6> -and it's Developers</h6></h3>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133141/discussion-on-answer-by-deep-jquery-scroll-to-element-does-not-animate-my-scroll).

Comment: Yep this worked. Thanks @Deep for your time helping me!

Comment: @RickJellema NP :) glad i could help